# Exponential Algorithm with Addition

Tags: c++, exponentiation

I'm trying to calculate the power of a number x^n, by just using pure addition like this: 2^4= 2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2 =16 so im using the following code to calculate 2^n:

```
add = x
for ( i = 1; i <= n-1; i++){
    add = add + add;
}
cout<< x << "^" << n << " = " << add << endl;
```

so if you want to calculate 3^4 you have to put `add = add + add + add` so my question is how do I make it work with any number that the user wants?

Comment: `cin >> x; cin >> n;`

Comment: Not to your question but conceptually, I would iterate `i` from `2` to `n`.

Answer (score 3):

For base b to the x <=> b^x

**in C and with STRICTLY addition**

```
int sum = b;
int add = b;
for (int i = 0; i < n+(-1); ++i) {
    add = sum;
    for (int j = 0; j < b+(-1); ++j) {
        sum += add;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think C is fine for me

Comment: @oglox answer updated. Please accept if this works for you :)

Comment: That isn't pure addition, you have a multiply.

Comment: It looks to me like this would calculate `n*pow(b,2)` and not `pow(b,n)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// first deal with pow = 1 or 0 cases not shown here
// pseudocode for pow >= 2
var = 0
for (i = 0; i < num^(pow - 2); i++)  // ^ is raising to power, not xor
    for (j = 0; j < num; j++) 
        var += num
```

As you can see with the "i" condition check you have to use the power function anyway so not really possible with pure addition

Comment: What use is XOR here?

Comment: No it's not xor, it's raising it to the power(this is pseudocode)